# Error: $controller:ctrlreg The controller with the name '{0}' is not registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-controller

**app.js**

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
    .config(config)

config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
}
})();
```

**home.controller.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('HomeController', HomeController);

HomeController.$inject = ['UserService', '$rootScope'];
function HomeController(UserService, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.bodylayout ='main_page_que';
    var vm = this;
}
})();
```

**home.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('RedCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.OpenRed = function() {
$scope.userRed = !$scope.userRed;
$scope.userBlue = false;
  }
  $scope.HideRed = function() {
$scope.userRed = false;
  }
  $scope.OpenBlue = function() {
$scope.userBlue = !$scope.userBlue;
$scope.userRed = false;
  };
  $scope.HideBlue = function() {
$scope.userBlue = false;
  };
});
```

**home.html**

```
<div ng-controller="RedCtrl">
    <a href="#" ng-click="OpenRed()" hide-red="HideRed()">Show Red</a>
    <div hide-red="HideRed()" class="loginBox" ng-show="userRed"></div>
    <a href="#" ng-click="OpenBlue()" hide-blue="HideBlue()">Show Blue</a>
    <div hide-blue="HideBlue()" class="loginBoxBlue" ng-show="userBlue"></div>
</div>
```

**Index.html**

```
    <html lang="pl" ng-app="app">
<body class="{{bodylayout}}">
<div class="content">
    <div ng-view style="margin:auto"></div>
</div>  
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="home.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="authentication.service.js"></script>
<script src="flash.service.js"></script>
<script src="user.service.local-storage.js"></script>
<script src="home/home.controller.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Hey, this is part from application when I use ngRoute and dynamically add `home.html`, but I think I have wrong app.js or home.controller.js beacuse when I add external file `home.js` (when is `ng-controller=""RedCtrl`. I get error `[$controller:ctrlreg] RedCtrl is not register`. Have you ideas why? I am new in Angular and I think the main reason is lack of my knowledge.

Comment: Declare your ng-app

Comment: I declared ng-app in index.html which I not inserted in this question

Comment: See [AngularJS Error Reference - $controller:ctrlreg](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$controller/ctrlreg)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are overwriting `app` module in *home.js* thus getting the error

*Use*

```
var app = angular.module('app'); //Get previously defined module
```

instead of

```
var app = angular.module('app', []); //It declares new module
```

---

You also need to change the sequence of JavaScript files

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="home.js"></script>
```