# Controller not recognized in AngularJS 1.5.7

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

Yet another troubling situation with a new project:

Following controller code:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('offerRequest', [])
    .controller('offerRequestCtrl', offerRequestCtrl);

offerRequestCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location'];

function offerRequestCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
    // controller code starts here.

    /* jshint validthis:true */
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'offerRequestCtrl';

    activate();

    function activate() { }
}
})();
```

With the following routing:

```
  // state for requesting offers
    .state('offerrequest', {
        url: '/offerrequest',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/offerrequest/offerrequest.html',
        controller: 'offerRequestCtrl'
    })
```

Causes the following error message:

```
   Argument 'offerRequestCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Tried the older style of defining it:

```
   angular.module('offerRequest', [])
    .controller('offerRequestCtrl', function offerRequestCtrl() {

    });
```

Throws the same error. What could I be doing wrong in the first implementation which I would like to work with?

Comment: have you used `.module('offerRequest', [])` somewhere else?

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr or jsfiddle ?

Comment: @satpal yes I have, in another service I'm using. Is that uncorrect way? I removed the service and it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: `(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('offerRequest', [])
        .factory('offerRequestService', offerRequestService);

    offerRequestService.$inject = ['$location'];

    function offerRequestService($location) {
        // controller code starts here.

        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'offerRequestService';

        activate();

        function activate() { }
    }
})();
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: $controller:ctrlreg The controller with the name '{0}' is not registered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512892/error-controllerctrlreg-the-controller-with-the-name-0-is-not-registered)

Comment: You can only define module once

Comment: It seems without declaring dependencies I can use the module in the service aswell. Thanks alot for your input, @Satpal

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the module declared with dependencies only globally,

```
angular
    .module('offerRequest', [])
```

Change your controller as,

```
angular
    .module('offerRequest')
    .controller('offerRequestCtrl', offerRequestCtrl);
```

Comment: I removed the dependencies from the service but not the controller and it works now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I cannot accept new answer until 4 minutes. Sorry, I will after that.

Comment: @Satpal  Well its tradition for us to remind other to accept answer ;)

Comment: @Sajeetharan  Well its tradition for us to remind other to accept answer ;)

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal, Give OP same slack and time to accept before. If OP has never accepted an answer then its OK otherwise its IMHO begging